# Null to lowercase fails on local, but not on staging. Help me to understand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, null

Faced the problem that I cannot understand and it itches my mind. I have a code, that was running fine for 3 weeks. Then for whatever reason it started to crash today and show an error. Which is technically correct behavior.

**The problem is that with the same data and the same code it works fine with ZERO crashes on a staging environment. Unit.title is null in multiple items on staging and on local.** And it was running excellent before on my local.

I've stashed all my changes and switched to branches as on staging - still continue to crash.

How to track the difference? How to check it? **Other devs don't have it.**

The code itself is stupidly easy:

```
          let costumeTitle = siteMap[data][unit].title;
          // if(!costumeTitle){
          //   console.log('unit', unit);
          //   console.log(data);
          //   costumeTitle = 'Broken title!'
          // }
          const lowerCaseTitle = costumeTitle.toLowerCase();
```

In some cases title indeed is null. And it is correct that it throw an error in React. But why now, why not before ? 3 weeks and everything is fine. On Stagin data is the same. And there are nulls as title also, but it works!

To clarify:

IN staging and in local data is the same. They both have unit.title equal null or undefined.

Comment: Any chance something in the staging environment could convert the `null` value to a `"null"` string? Any difference in the database, the communication protocol maybe?

Comment: I will edit original post. In stagin environment as in local there ara data with title null.

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases title indeed is null.

Then `costumeTitle.toLowerCase()` will throw, because you can't access property `toLowerCase` on `null`.

> But why now, why not before ?

Because it never came up before, coincidentally `title` was always non-`null` when that code ran. That's the only reason you wouldn't have gotten the error.

---

Side note: If you want to set `lowerCaseTitle` to `null` when `costumeTitle` is `null`, you can do that with optional chaining (`?.`) and nullish coalescing (`??`):

```
const lowerCaseTitle = costumeTitle?.toLowerCase() ?? null;
//    ^−− will be a string if costumeTitle is string, or null if
//        costumeTitle is null (or undefined)
```

If it's okay for `lowerCaseTitle` to be `undefined` rather than `null` when `costumeTitle` is `null`, you don't need the nullish coalescing:

```
const lowerCaseTitle = costumeTitle?.toLowerCase();
//    ^−− will be a string if costumeTitle is string, or undefined
//        if costumeTitle is null (or undefined)
```

Comment: I've edited my original post for clarification. What you are writing is correct, but as I've mentioned - data is the same. There are nulls as unit.title both in staging and in local. 

Problem is why null on staging doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @VolodymyrRT - Again: If you execute the code `costumeTitle.toLowerCase()` when `costumeTitle` is `null`, you **will** get an error. There is no wiggle room or subtlety there, it **will** happen. :-) So again: If you didn't see this error on staging, it's because that code was never run with a `null` on staging.

Comment: And again, I know that. Believe me. That is the reason why I post it. Same code, same data, 2 different behaviors.

Comment: @VolodymyrRT - So to my mind, FWIW, your best bet is to focus on in your debugging on: A) Why would I not be getting nulls in this code if it's in the DB? Or B) Why would this code path not be followed in staging? Etc. **That** will help you figure out what's going on, rather than focussing on what you know *isn't* happening. Good luck with it! :-)